# Rails how to use console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a rookie in Rails. My ultimate goal is to add a user in `devise` (I know it's not a good practise but I only need to do it once). I've seen that you can run commands at the runtime in Rails for Zombies tutorial. (http://railsforzombies.org/levels/1/challenges/1)

This is basically what I want to do. I am using RubyMine and I run the rails application by either running the application or using `rails s`. However whatever I type is not executed as I do not get any error or any print outs.

So my question is how can I actually execute a command in the console for Rails app?

Comment: Just run the console and execute your commands. Also, do not rely too much on rubymine, it can't do some things properly or is unnecessarily heavy (for such simple task as running a console)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***Open terminal -> Go in your app directory by cd command -> type "rails console" or "rails c" -> write your code***

To add a new user you can do:

```
User.create(name: "user_name", email: "user_email", password: "your_password")
```

Also you should checkout [`Rails command line`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html)

Comment: @SarpKaya what you mean by not changing anything from the webapp? Can you explain?

Comment: It is not adding anything to User model.

Comment: @SarpKaya i wrote a sample code to create to a user as i don't know what fields you have in your user model, you need to write your attributes inside create statement. I think you are getting validation errors. You can use .new and then .valid which will validate your initialized user and if you see it returns false then you can check errors by .errors method

Comment: My bad, I needed to save it. Thanks for that

Answer (score 1):

```
rails c
```

And you can also use:

```
rails c -s
```

"-s" stands for sandbox so you can play around without breaking anything. Operations will be automatically reverted when you leave the console.

You can then write:

```
user = User.new
```

Answer (score 0):

rails console: The console command lets you interact with your Rails application from the command line.

> You can also use the alias "c" to invoke the console: rails c.